# Apply water ripple effect with JavaScript in HTML video player

Tags: javascript, html, web, ripple

I am trying to create a [water ripple effect](http://www.learningjquery.com/2016/06/10-jquery-plugins-to-create-a-ripple-effect) in a video embedded in HTML5 default web player.

I am doing it fine with using images and and a overlay canvas on top of it, but what I am trying to do now is to get single frames from a video and output it to a canvas every 1-5ms using [this tutorial](http://www.kaizou.org/2012/09/frame-by-frame-video-effects-using-html5-and/).

And I am stuck at this point, I can output frame into another canvas using
`canvas.toDataURL()` function.

I have seen advanced web-based video players that allow for applying Processing.js sketches on top of videos, would that be a good solution?

My question is: what would be the best and most reliable solution for applying visual effects (water ripples in this case) using JavaScript to a video playing in HTML5 media player.

Comment: That's broad. Too broad. Share what you've got now if you want us to give you some help. But one thing: don't ever call `toDataURL` to draw a canvas over an other. For 2d context, `drawImage` does accept `<canvas>` element as source.

Comment: Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esteewhy/5Ht3b/6/) Probably you're looking for this. Do let me know if it helps or not.

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle of the work you have done.

Answer (score 4):

> My question is: what would be the best and most reliable solution for applying visual effects (water ripples in this case) using JavaScript to a video playing in HTML5 media player.

In my opinion the *best* approach would be to use WebGL to create the effects, using the video as input texture and a simple flat geometry that is manipulated using a animated bump-map - or -  directly manipulating the vertices - or - a perhaps a shader program, and then output the result to a canvas.

I would not place the video in DOM at all but create control buttons and display *those* together with the output [webgl-]canvas in DOM.

The obvious drawback would be besides from slightly more complex code, when used on computers which doesn't have a GPU (but that would be a drawback in any case and more so if you used a regular 2D canvas and pixel manipulation).

This is of course very broad in terms of code example. But I assume you get the general idea.

A couple of notes:

> [...] what I am trying to do now is to get single frames from a video and output it to a canvas every 1-5ms [...]

This is sort of pointless in regards to the time-budget, as the typical monitor can only refresh the image every ~16.7ms which means you're wasting at least 3-4 frames that are never displayed.

Also, a typical video source never runs faster than 30 FPS (in the US, 25 FPS in Europe) which means there is only a new frame every 33.3ms (there are of course special case videos such as VR/AR, stereoscopic, games and "Mac" recorded video etc. that *may* use higher fps - but for the most part anything > 30 fps is usually wasted cycles) which allows for a higher time-budget for processing per frame.

> I can output frame into another canvas using canvas.toDataURL() function [...]

Outch! :) This comes which a **huge** overhead. The browser would have to use line filtering (in case of PNG - well, some browsers skip this and use filter 0), compression, base-64 encoding, then apply the source to an image element, decode the base-64, decompress, defilter...

You can instead simply use the source canvas for [`drawImage()`](https://devdocs.io/dom/canvasrenderingcontext2d/drawimage) *directly* and only have to deal with a in-memory bitmap (super fast!).

All that being said: if simplicity is important code-wise, you can of course do all this using a 2D canvas. You can use `drawImage()` to displace pixels/blocks and therefor work on the GPU (but not necessarily faster than working on the bitmap directly depending on how you apply the actual displacement).

But there are still many caveats such as video source and destination resolution which has a exponential impact on performance, limited use of the GPU as you still would have to do multiple *serial* operations versus parallel operations with webgl/gpu and so forth. In essence, the performance *will* suffer compared to a webgl solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get high performance you can use WebGL. Following is a github reop for Water ripple project.

https://github.com/sirxemic/jquery.ripples/

Following is a ruining example for jQuery WebGL Ripples

http://sirxemic.github.io/jquery.ripples/

Think this might help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways. You can write core javascript code with canvas.
But I think it is best to use Jquery plugins. There are several plugins available for water ripple.

You may check the following links:

https://github.com/virtyaluk/paper-ripple

https://github.com/sirxemic/jquery.ripples

https://github.com/andyvr/water-ripple